# get all the photos of a product

Tags: twig, opencart-3

I made a special slider for the products on the catalog page. However, I cannot bring the images of the product in a loop. How can I get all the photos of the product?

This is the product_card.twig file. I want to create a for loop based on the product.

[product_card.twig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x3TN.png)

```
{% for image in product.images %}

     <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block" src="{{ images.thumb }}" alt="product-img">
      </div>

  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hey Berk, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I wrote an example thanks.

Comment: what does your controller look like? Are you passing data for all the products images to the .twig, or just a single thumbnail?